# Reinitialize an already loaded angular component

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there a way to reinitialize a component in angular 4, when user clicks a link which navigate to the already loaded/existing route?

I need this functionality because user can be viewing the form in edit mode with pre-populated data and decides not to edit and fill in a new form (which is already loaded).

Comment: Can't you just just reset the form?

Comment: @YounesM yes, I want to reset the form, but since the component is already loaded, clicking again on the link doesn't run ngOnInit again. That's why the form is not getting reset

Comment: you will find here an example on how to handle parameter change without reinitializing your component (https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action)

Comment: you could use ngOnChanges 
https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

Comment: @AliTurabAbbasi tried with ngOnChanges(), didn't worked out. Also I don't want to reset my form always, I want to reset only if it is pre populated ( for editing ) and user clicks on new form link instead of editing and submitting the form.

Comment: If you are navigating to a route that you have already visited then still angular calls its ngOnInit because when you navigate away the component is destroyed. So what you can do is get data if you are in edit mode and then use PatchValue

Comment: @AliTurabAbbasi what you are saying is correct that if we navigate away the component gets destroyed, but in my case I was not navigating away from the already loaded component.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to resolve my issue. I used queryParams in url with flag as true/false depending from where user is navigating to "new form" page. If it is true I reset the form otherwise not.